# Discord.py find channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a help "log" command in discord.

````
@client.command()
async def logs(ctx):
 for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
  if channel.name == "henry-logs":
     await ctx.send("Henry Logs channel is already setup. If you have access to it, it should be available in the channel list")
  else:
   await ctx.send("Henry logs channel is not found! If you have such access please create channel named **EXACTLY**")
   await ctx.send("```henry-logs```")
````

However it doesn't send the not found message once, but for every channel that is not "henry-logs", since I used for channel in build.

Is there a way I can fix it and send it only once if the channel doesn't exist and once if does exist?

Comment: Have any of the given answers answered your question? If so, please mark it as the accepted answer to close this question. If there are still some errors or any unexpected behaviors you are seeing, please provide more details as part of your question or comment on the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always create the channel. So the user doesn't need to create it manually. Preventing the bug that you're getting from happening in the first place.

```py
channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel('henry-logs')
```

After the channel is made you could assign permissions such as:

```
await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
```

This will stop any non-manage channel permission members from sending messages in the channel.

---

## Update

Sorry, i understand your question now:

Just break the for loop and set a temporary channel variable:

````py
tempchan = null
for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
  if channel.name == "henry-logs":
     await ctx.send("Henry Logs channel is already setup. If you have access to it, it should be available in the channel list")
     tempchan = channel
     break;
if tempchan == null:
  await ctx.send("Henry logs channel is not found! If you have such access please create channel named **EXACTLY**")
   await ctx.send("```henry-logs```")
````

If the variable is null - you send the message, if not, do what you need to do with the found channel.

Comment: That's good, but still it would create a new channel for each channel that's not with that name. For example, there's 5 non-matching channels, it will create 5 channels. That's my main issue.

Comment: Sorry! Check my latest edit, i totally misunderstood your question. @DeyanNikolov

Comment: It's pretty much the same. It prints out 4 times not found and one time found.

Comment: Have you removed the else statement?

Comment: I copy and pasted your message.

Comment: Copy-paste ruins indent, plus you never learn by copy and pasting.

Comment: Are you running multiple instances of the bot by accident?

Comment: I mean I fixed the indent, also I changed null to None since it makes error.

Comment: No, it's one instance.

Answer (score 0):

First I'll help you solve the problem of checking if the channel exists. You can have a look at how to use [`any` here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/any). This is a quick way to iterate through a guild's channels, and if any of the channels have that name, it will fulfil the `if` statement and return `True`.

````py
@client.command()
async def logs(ctx):
    if any("henry-logs" in channel.name for channel in ctx.guild.channels): # if there's any henry-logs channels, it will return True
        await ctx.send("Henry Logs channel is already setup. If you have access to it, it should be available in the channel list")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Henry logs channel is not found! If you have such access please create channel named **EXACTLY**")
        await ctx.send("```henry-logs```")
````

[image: Above code working]

If you're not a fan of *condensed* code like the above, the following does the same thing. The bot iterates through all the channels in the guild, and returns a channel object if a channel `henry-logs` can be found, which is something the previous code didn't do.

```py
# replaced if statement
channel_found = None
for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
    if "henry-logs" in channel.name:
        channel_found = channel
        break
if channel_found != None:
    await ctx.send(f"{channel_found.mention} is already setup.")
else:
    await ctx.send("Henry logs channel is not found! If you have such access please create channel named **henry-logs**")
```

[image: Code works the exact same way]

---

If you want to automatically create the channel, you can replace what's in your `else` statement with the following.

```py
@client.command()
async def logs(ctx):
    # this uses the first if-else statement I had shown!
    if any("henry-logs" in channel.name for channel in ctx.guild.channels):
        await ctx.send("Henry Logs channel is already setup. If you have access to it, it should be available in the channel list")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Henry logs channel is not found! I'm creating a channel now~")
        try:
            channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel('henry-logs')
        except: # raised if the bot doesn't have sufficient permissions
            await ctx.send("I couldn't create a `henry-logs` channel.. please make one for me, thanks!")
            return
        await ctx.send(f"I successfully created the channel {channel.mention}!")
```

[image: Above code working]